# HMTL5 / UTF8 using FastCGI in C (fcgi_stdio.h)

Tags: c, html, utf-8, fastcgi

This example works fine for me:

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h"

int main(void) {

while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0) {

    //Standard FastCGI Example Web-page
    printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "<title>FactCGI Example</title>"
        "<h1>Example Website</h1>"
        "Some text...\r\n");

    FCGI_Finish();
}

return 0;
}
```

But since I need UTF8 chars on my web-page, I thought I'd format the web page using html5.  This was my skeleton which renders ok as a stand-alone file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>FactCGI Example</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Example Website</h1>
<p>Some text...</p>
</body>

</html>
```

But when folded this into the fcgi script as follows, I get an 'Internal Server Error' on script load.

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h"

int main(void) {

while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0) {

    //Using html5 for the web-page
    printf("<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n"
        "<html>\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "<head>\r\n"
        "<title>FactCGI Example</title>\r\n"
        "</head>\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "<body>\r\n"
        "<h1>Example Website</h1>\r\n"
        "<p>Some text...</p>\r\n"
        "</body>\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "</html>\r\n");

    FCGI_Finish();
    }

return 0;
}
```

Fedora 23, httpd 2.8.18, Firefox 43.0.3, gcc 5.3.1-2

Googling indicates all fcgi, web pages start with "Content-type: text/html".

Have I made some silly mistake or does fcgi just not support html5?

Is there some other way to enable UTF8 support using fcgi?

Comment: Aren't you missing the Content-type header in your HTML5 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is likely caused because you don't have the Content-type HTTP header in your output. Also, if you want to use UTF-8, then you should specify UTF-8 as the charset in the Content-type header. But you don't need to use HTML5 to use UTF-8 in your web page; the encoding can be used with older HTML versions as well.

Here's your code with the Content-type header and UTF-8 parameter added.

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h"

int main(void) {

while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0) {

    //Using html5 for the web-page
    printf("Content-type: text/html charset=utf-8\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n"
        "<html>\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "<head>\r\n"
        "<title>FactCGI Example</title>\r\n"
        "</head>\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "<body>\r\n"
        "<h1>Example Website</h1>\r\n"
        "<p>Some text...</p>\r\n"
        "</body>\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "</html>\r\n");

    FCGI_Finish();
    }

return 0;
}
```